# Possible to go over nested lists with for loops in a similar way to dicts?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My function is made to get the area of any arbitrary triangle.

Here is the way that I know works

```
def areaOfTriangle(vertices):
    x1 = vertices[0][0]
    y1 = vertices[0][1]
    x2 = vertices[1][0]
    y2 = vertices[1][1]
    x3 = vertices[2][0]
    y3 = vertices[2][1]
    area = (1.0/2.0)*(x2*y3 - x3*y2 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x1*y2 - x2*y1)
    return area
```

However, I think this is crap so here's what I had as a sketched out thought,

```
def areaOfTriangle(vertices):
    coord1 = vertices[0]
    coord2 = vertices[1]
    coord3 = vertices[2]
    for x1,y1 in coord1:
        for x2, y2 in coord2:
            for x3, y3 in coord3:
                area = (1.0/2.0)*(x2*y3 - x3*y2 - x1*y3 + x3*y1 + x1*y2 - x2*y1)
    return area
```

However, this apparently doesn't play too nice with lists. I thought this would work in the way that once can get keys and values from dictionaries...but lists don't have the iteritems() method. Then I thought about converting the lists into dictionaries, but the keys are unique in dicts and hence they only pop up once....which would make my function not work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use tuple unpacking:

```
(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) = vertices
```

Python can unpack nested sequences into separate variables, as long as you create the *same* nesting structure on the left-hand-side.

The looping will not work because you are trying to unpack 2-value tuples *per loop iteration*, where the iteration would only yield only 1 value.

This works across python versions.

Demonstration:

```
>>> vertices = [(1,2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) = vertices
>>> print x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm a little confused about having the object values on the left side of the assignment symbol. I thought this was usually a no no in python. Is this an one off quirk of the language?

Comment: There are no values on the left-hand side, only names to assign to. Nested tuple assignment targets is a *feature* of the language. :-)

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements for the full syntax for `target`.